# Reading multiple data from multiple databases in vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010

I have 11 Access database files each having 20 items which needs to be stored in local variables as 
**RejRsnStn(i)(Reason)** where **i** stands for station number 1 to 11 & **Reason** stands for Reason 1 to 20.

I am reading this data in following way:

```
Public Sub ReadReasonCodes()
    'Station 1
    For Reason = 1 To 20
        DatafileStn = "E:\DATANetwork\DATAStation_1.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxx"
        Dim ConnstringStn As String = provider & DatafileStn
        connstringwrkstn = ConnstringStn
        myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnstringStn
        myConnection.Open()

        str = "SELECT * FROM Table_Config WHERE StationNo = 1"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            RejRsnStn1(Reason) = If(IsDBNull(dr("RejectionReason" & Reason)), "NA", dr("RejectionReason" & Reason))
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
    Next

    'Station 2
    For Reason = 1 To 20
        DatafileStn = "E:\DATANetwork\DATAStation_2.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxx"
        Dim ConnstringStn As String = provider & DatafileStn
        connstringwrkstn = ConnstringStn
        myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnstringStn
        myConnection.Open()

        str = "SELECT * FROM Table_Config WHERE StationNo = 2"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()
            RejRsnStn2(Reason) = If(IsDBNull(dr("RejectionReason" & Reason)), "NA", dr("RejectionReason" & Reason))
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
    Next

End Sub
```

Can you please guide me with a concise method.

Thanks in advance.
Prashant.

Comment: Move all the connection stuff outside the loops.

Comment: it boggles me that you use a loop for the reason code, but utterly fail to use them for the station id.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no, you can not haz teh codez.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

First I would import System.Data.OleDb and then construct a class to contain all the codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class rCode
    Dim _ReasonCode As String = ""
    Public Property ReasonCode() As String
        Get
            Return _ReasonCode
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
        _ReasonCode = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class RCodes
    Public Property Station_1_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_2_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_3_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_4_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_5_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_6_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_7_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_8_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_9_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_10_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
    Public Property Station_11_Reasoncodes As New List(Of rCode)
End Class
```

Then I would initiate the class I just created:

```
public class form1
    Public ReasonCodes As RCodes = New RCodes
```

Then I would make a subroutine to get the twenty codes from a database:

```
public class form1
    Public ReasonCodes As RCodes = New RCodes

    Public Sub GetReasonCodes(station As String)
    Dim Provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection
    Dim DatafileStn As String = "E:\DATANetwork\DATAStation_" & station & ".accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxx"
    Dim ConnstringStn As String = Provider & DatafileStn
    myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnstringStn
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table_Config WHERE StationNo = " & station, myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim s As rCode = New rCode
    Dim s2 As New List(Of rCode)
    While dr.Read()
        For Reason = 1 To 20
            If IsDBNull(dr("RejectionReason" & CStr(Reason))) Then s.ReasonCode = "NA" Else s.ReasonCode = CStr(dr("RejectionReason" & CStr(Reason)))
            s2.Add(s)
        Next
    End While
    If Not dr.IsClosed Then dr.Close()
    myConnection.Close()
    dr = Nothing
    myConnection = Nothing
    Select Case station
        Case "1"
            ReasonCodes.Station_1_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "2"
            ReasonCodes.Station_2_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "3"
            ReasonCodes.Station_3_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "4"
            ReasonCodes.Station_4_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "5"
            ReasonCodes.Station_5_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "6"
            ReasonCodes.Station_6_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "7"
            ReasonCodes.Station_7_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "8"
            ReasonCodes.Station_8_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "9"
            ReasonCodes.Station_9_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "10"
            ReasonCodes.Station_10_Reasoncodes = s2
        Case "11"
            ReasonCodes.Station_11_Reasoncodes = s2
    End Select
End Sub
```

Then, I would make the initiator:

```
    Public Sub ReadReasonCodes()
        For i As Integer = 1 To 11
            GetReasonCodes(CStr(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

you can access your data from the class "ReasonCodes"

EXA:

```
Dim Stn6_code15 = ReasonCodes.Station_6_Reasoncodes(14).ReasonCode
'Note: since reasoncodes are stored in an Array, they are 0 based. 
'So ReasonCodes.Station_6_Reasoncodes(14).ReasonCode = 
'station 6, reason code 15.
```

Of course, I cannot test this, as I have no access DB files, but it should work, and if not it may require minor tweaks to obtain your goal.

Hope this helps you.